# Can't delete Sharepoint folders created by Microsoft Graph API but can delete ones created in web browser

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I can delete files and folders created directly in SharePoint and Teams via web browser or desktop app.

But when I create a folder via Microsoft Graph API, the delete option is not shown in the drop down menu in the web browser or desktop app, and when I try to delete that folder using the Microsoft Graph API I get a 403 Error (a permission issue, I believe).

I'm an owner of the team/site with read and write permissions.

Here's the API info used to create the folder:

```
POST /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children
```

BODY

```
{
    "name": "1 Proposal",
    "folder": { },
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

And the one to delete:

```
DELETE /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
```

Is there something I should put in the body when creating the folder to help with permissions (inherited from parent folder or something)?

Comment: Please check if the permissions are present in the token or not by heading to [JWT.ms](jwt.ms) and paste your token. Which account are you using? Is it a Work account or MSA account?

Comment: Hi Shiva. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Wondering where I can find the token. Am using Microsoft Graph and Integromat. Any insight?

Comment: Hi @team_willis, from where are you testing these calls?

Comment: From Integromat. Signed in through usual MS login credentials (username, password).

Comment: The behavior is like a channel still exists for the folder I can't delete (or move or rename). But when I list the channels for the team, there is no channel associated with the folder (only there General channel).

Comment: I recommend also checking the permission settings in SharePoint. Settings > Library settings > More library settings > Versioning settings > Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?